# How do you Deflate data and put it into a vector?

Tags: c++, zlib, c++20

With [zstr, a header-only C++ zlib wrapper library](https://github.com/mateidavid/zstr), I’m trying to *Deflate* a `std::string` and put it into a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

```cpp
zstr::ostream deflating_stream(std::cout);
deflating_stream.write(content.data(), content.size());
```

The above code works: it prints the Deflate’d. The problem is, I’m not familiar with C++ streams and I cannot get it into a `std::vector`. Tried several times in vain with `std::ostringstream`, `std::ostream`, `std::istringstream`, `std::istreambuf_iterator`, `std::streambuf`, `.rdbuf()`, et cetera, and the only thing that came out was an emptiness output (`.tellp() == 0`).

How do I *Deflate* a `std::string` and put it into a `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

---

The following is some of my tries. I have no idea how to access the Deflate’d data.

```cpp
std::istringstream is;
std::ostream ss(is.rdbuf());
zstr::ostream deflating_stream(ss);
deflating_stream.write(
    uncompressed_string.data(),
    uncompressed_string.size()
);
the_vector.insert(
    the_vector.cend(),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

```cpp
std::ostringstream oss;
zstr::ostream deflating_stream(oss);
deflating_stream.write(
    uncompressed_string.data(),
    uncompressed_string.size()
);
const std::string deflated = oss.str();
the_vector.insert(
    the_vector.cend(),
    deflated.cbegin(),
    deflated.cend()
);
```

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
zstr::ostream deflating_stream(ss);
deflating_stream.write(
    uncompressed_string.data(),
    uncompressed_string.size()
);
std::string deflated = ss.str();
std::cout << deflated.size(); // Says 0.
```

Comment: I'm a bit dense. You have a `std::string` which contains compressed data and you want to end up with the decompressed data in a `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: If so then I think you are over-complicating things. Just read bytes from your zstr stream and add the bytes to your vector. A simple loop, no need for any fancy stream classes.

Comment: @john, what you read is correct. Could you please tell me how I can read bytes from the `ostream` or its underlying `streambuf`? Sorry, it actually might be trivial, but it’s really the part I failed at.

Comment: From an `ostream` just use something like `for (char ch; str.get(ch); ) { ... }`. `get` will read a single character (byte) from an input stream and (effectively) return false if the read failed.

Comment: Oh, wait, it is the other way around. I’m trying to _compress_ the `std::string`, the _uncompressed data_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include "zstr.hpp"

int main() {
  std::string text{"some text\n"};
  std::stringbuf buffer;
  zstr::ostream compressor{&buffer};

  // Must flush to get complete gzip data in buffer
  compressor << text << std::flush;

  // It's probably easier to use just the string...
  auto compstr = buffer.str();
  std::vector<unsigned char> deflated;
  deflated.resize(compstr.size());
  std::copy(compstr.begin(), compstr.end(), deflated.begin());

  std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(deflated.data()), deflated.size());
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling:

```sh
$ ./a.out | zcat
some text
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! As the `zstr::ostream` constructor does not directly accept an `std::stringbuf` _with additional options_, instead, I used a `zstr::ostreambuf` and linked it to `std::ostream`: `std::stringbuf deflated_data_buffer; zstr::ostreambuf deflating_stream_buffer(&deflated_data_buffer, A_MEBIBYTE_IN_BYTES, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION, 15); std::ostream deflating_stream(&deflating_stream_buffer);`. Thank you so much for saving my day.